# Is there an idiomatic way to get a vectorized conditional mean in R

Tags: r, mean

I want to use a vectorized conditional average (when using `ddply` and `transform`) meaning an average of entries that pass a certain condition. I came up with this but am wondering if it can be implemented using built-in functions or a popular package?

```
mean.conditional <- function(x, cond, zero = 0) {
  filter <- cond(x)
  return(sum(ifelse(filter, x, zero)) / sum(filter))
}
```

alternatively, the following function is probably even cleaner:

```
mean.conditional <- function(x, filter) {
  return(sum(ifelse(filter, x, 0)) / sum(filter))
```

Comment: `weighed.mean(x, cond)` ?

Comment: Is `cond` a function or a vector? Your two functions don't seem to agree...

Comment: @hadley: curiously, I see that `weighted.mean(c())` returns `NaN`, as does Joshua's solution (similar implementation I assume.) Shouldn't the result be `NA`, as `mean(c())` gives?

Comment: ... and now I found that `mean(NA, na.rm = TRUE)` is also `NaN`. Love the consistency...

Comment: @flodel `c()` is the same as `NULL` - `numeric()` is probably a better test case.

Comment: I just found that out, I confirm, thanks.

Comment: @flodel thanks, I fixed it so that the variables agree, you were right to spot that the second takes in a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `mean(x[cond(x)])` do what you want?

Comment: `cond` applied to `x` will give a series of true and false values which cannot be used as indices into `x`; I think.

Comment: Did you actually try it?  Logical indices are an idiomatic part of R: see for example [http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/logical-index-vector](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/logical-index-vector)

Comment: Tried it, fascinating, this is much cleaner. Comes out to `mean(x[filter])`.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a built-in function, but this will do it:

```
sum(x*filter) / sum(filter)
```

Comment: `mean(c(1,2,3) * c(T,F,F))` gives `0.3333333`.

Comment: `sum(c(1,1,NaN) * c(T,T,F)) / sum(c(T,T,F))` gives `NaN` rather than `1`.

Comment: @Peteris: then set `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: Is `sum(x * filter, na.rm=T)` more idiomatic than `sum(ifelse(filter, x, 0))`?

Comment: I don't know it's necessarily "more idiomatic", but it's an order of magnitude faster.